# XNA C# Object reference Array

Tags: c#, arrays, xna

I've looked at multiple solutions, but none seems to help with my question. How would one come to make a object reference for a 3d array in c#?

Answer (score 0):

Well, whats wrong with:

```
var my3dArray = new int[2, 2, 2];
```

Or if you know the data:

```
var my3dArray = new int[,,] { { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } },
                              { { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } } };
```

Comment: I'm making static public int[,,] map = new int[Layer, Row, Col]; which is made out of static int of Layer, Row and Col so i need to make a object reference or else the array is not made.

Comment: @SeanYi I'm sorry, I have no idea what you are trying to say.